# Improve search for duplicates by searching answers not questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I just worked the close queue and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348509/boolean-array-nullpointerexception).

I'm certain the (Boolean)null -> boolean -> NullPointerException has already happened, so there is most likely already a question out there addressing this.

But I can't find it, because the questions most likely won't contain the relevant keywords (boxing in this case).

So, I'd like to search for answers because they will most likely contain the relevant sentence "Your problem is due to Java trying to boxing this null to a boolean which is impossible" in the beginning.

In the close->duplicate screen I would like to have a toggle on the side to search & display the content of the answers the same way currently questions are displayed.

Comment: You can always open another window to do the search, then paste the URL into the close box.

Comment: @Barmar Enlighten me, how can I explicitly search for answers?

Comment: With `is:answer` in the search criteria.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! I still want that feature, though, as it eases the work process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use the built-in advanced search features](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). In particular, `is:answer`:

- [`[java] box null boolean is:answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+box+null+boolean+is%3Aanswer)

Documentation:

> `is:question` narrows results down to just questions, and `is:answer` returns only answers

I know you said you still want the ability to just toggle this restriction, but really, it's already available through the above `:/`