# Searching for questions to prevent duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, search

Good search is important to prevent duplicated questions. Duplicate question are annoying for someone who want to find an existing similar answer, so he/she can find the solution directly. Without the need to ask a new question. It is also annoying for the reader, and for the person who wants to answer the question.

But how to achieve that? I had a few times I could not find a similar problem myself, and in the reply was said it was a duplicate question. Reading the links they were right.

Similar questions do help a lot. A few times they prevent me to post my question. 
[Improve search for duplicates by searching answers not questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252580/improve-search-for-duplicates-by-searching-answers-not-questions)  is an improvement of searching, but not for this question.

My last question was [Python readability regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755132/python-readability-regex?noredirect=1#comment38408757_24755132)  It is about, as you might expect about readability of regex in Python. I search first on stackoverflow and later further on internet and found that in most languages this can be done with IgnorePatternWhitespace
But for Python it is not there, so I asked the question. It seems for Python re.VERBOSE would do that job. The first person replied that first and a few minutes later marked as a duplicate question. That was correct. If search on re.VERBOSE . So if you know the answer, you can find the (duplicate) question. But I you do not know the answer, and that is why I asked in the first place, you can not (or at least I could not find) the question and answer.

I do not care about this specific question, on the specific comment, nor the marking as duplicate, nor votes or something else. I am for me (and for others as well) just looking for a way to use StackOverflow even more efficient. Suggestions?

Comment: If you manage to solve the problem of how to direct people to the appropriate web page when the person searching doesn't actually know the appropriate terms for what they want to find then you could likely become a billionaire, as that's probably one of the more valuable inventions you could come up with in this day and age.

Comment: You do not have to pay me directly ;-). But for this specific question there could be made a link to Python and IgnorePatternWhitespace Not because Python supports IgnorePatternWhitespace, it does not but have the same functionality with a different name. Something like a association. Humans are very strong with association, programs not. So if the previous answer would be something like use re.VERBOSE in Python, which in other language often named as IgnorePatternWhitespace . So you would not even need to change the software. Adding votes for associations would help a lot.

Comment: The linking of duplicate questions is designed to do what you are asking. When your post gets indexed by search engines later searches of your terms will link to your question which will itself now point to the one that answers it using other terms. Appropriate results through duplicate chaining. This is also why duplicates do not get deleted.

Comment: Correct, but after the question is asked, not before. So there is a duplicate question.

Comment: Sure, but the current system (if working correctly) allows for variations in the way a question may be asked. These variations while they don't deserve answers (as they have those in the eventually tied in duplicates) are still valuable contributions in that they increase the ease of future people finding answers to their question using different terminology and keywords.

Comment: @Bernard: Really, `IgnorePatternWhitespace` is **not** a universal term, it is only used in C# (.NET). Perl uses a `x` flag (described as *Extend your pattern's legibility by permitting whitespace and comments*), in Java it is called the `COMMENTS` mode, etc.

Comment: @Bernard: and thus asking a duplicate question is *fine* and even great! Because now there is a post on the internet that asks about Python and `IgnorePatternWhitespace`, which acts as a way sign to the canonical question and answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My preference is to prevent duplicate questions. But I do agree, after after the question is asked the association is made.

Comment: @Bernard: So how do you propose we a) anticipate every possible keyword for every possible programming concept, and b) then efficiently store those? `IgnorePatternWhitespace` in the context of Python regular expressions would have been impossible to anticipate until .NET came along and used that term. What other terms are going to come up in the years to come? Crowdsourcing duplicates is way more efficient here; asking a duplicate using novel terms is **not a problem**, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course investigating in advance is not option. Crowdsourcing is a efficient way of cumulating of knowledge when needed. Your answer "IgnorePatternWhitespace is not a universal term" makes in this context hard (or impossible) to do. If there would be universal term there could be a solution. In this example I do agree with you duplicated items are the only way to increase knowledge. And so can not be prevented.

Comment: @Servy The more "valuable" problem to solve, in terms of becoming a billionaire, is how to direct people to a web page where they are most likely to make a purchase, irrespective of what they wanted to find. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **already** helped Stack Overflow become more efficient.

You asked a duplicate question, but using a unique context, with unique keywords. Anyone else now searching for *python* and *IgnorePatternWhiteSpace* will find your question and is then guided to the canonical question on the subject.

We cannot possibly anticipate every keyword anyone is ever going to use when asking a question. As such, asking a duplicate question after having searched is *fine*.

Note that your post was *not downvoted*. No one told you off. People helped you, then linked you to the canonical question. And in that process, we created the sign post for anyone using the same terms to find the solution.

Comment: Almost! There is an extra "you" as well. :)

Comment: @AirThomas: aaargh, can you come live in my spell checker now?