# Slapped for adding a comment to a good answer review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments

This is probably a known issue and I don't have any suggestion for improvement, as I agree with the current behavior, although I got bitten.

I was reviewing late answers and I came across [How can I prove to an outside party that a data file hasn't been tampered with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275493/how-can-i-prove-to-an-outside-party-that-a-data-file-hasnt-been-tampered-with/24275525#24275525):

I found it to be a good answer, so I hadn't decided to upvote or not, but I really wanted to leave a comment behind. The question asks for protection against **tampering** but the answer suggests a certificate to **sign** the contents. My comment was going to add that you really don't need something as strong as signing, as you could potentially just hash the content.

The curious thing, and I found this interesting, is that when I clicked the comment button I got bashed with the "STOP, LOOK and LISTEN", and while sometimes this is fair (been there), in this case my good will to try and add something to the answer got me bitten.

Like I said before, any suggestions that come to mind to fix this little thing would instead make the review process worse, so I'm just sharing as a curiosity, finding, name it whatever. I just know next time, I will apply the action (Upvote/Downvote/Skip) but save the link to comment afterwards.

Comment: totally, should I delete this one, it seems this was discussed.

Comment: leave it be. It will get marked as a duplicate and then people who come across it later will be led to the original. See this question from today for more reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265722/1590950

Comment: This is strange. You shouldn't fail an audit here for commenting. I don't even know how you can audit these types of questions. Was it expecting you to downvote or upvote? It has no downvotes so I presume the only auditable action it would have taken was an upvote. That being said, voting is arbitrary so this part of the review system is broken.

Comment: "Slapped on the wrist" indicates that you got a lesser punishment than you seem to have deserved. The body of your question suggests that you think that the reaction was too _severe_ (even if only slightly), so I've edited the title to correct the inconsistency.

Comment: agree @JoshCaswell.